# Installing Kali on a Dual partition USB

Tags: kali-linux, usb-drive, live-usb, bootable

I have a 32GB Kingston DataTraveler USB and I want to do the following:
-1 Partition to boot kali linux
-1 Partition to be used as data storage (for kali and windows)
-I want to give Kali the size it needs, and the rest be put in the storage partition.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

When installing Kali, create two partitions, one for Kali and another for your data. You'll want 10GB of space for Kali, and the remainder to be for your data. The Kali graphical installer will allow you to install all of Kali onto the 10GB partition. Make sure this remainder partition is NTFS, otherwise either Kali or Windows won't recognize it.

Comment: I tried installing through "Graphical Installation" but I cant figure out how to create the partitions.

Comment: Select Custom Partitions options when you get to that point, and you should be given a prompt to configure partitions.